# API Gateway mapping template for single change to request

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Using API Gateway, I would like to intercept the Integration Request, change the model and then forward it through to the endpoint via a body mapping template.

For example, I would like to change the MatterGUID property to be MatterId + value.

If i include my entire model within the template, it works fine;

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "Property1" : "$inputRoot.Property1",
  "MatterId" : "$inputRoot.MatterGUID",
  "Property2" : "$inputRoot.Property2",
  "Property3" : "$inputRoot.Property3"
}
```

However, I would like to update my model by updating only the field needing to be changed. i.e. something like:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "MatterId" : "$inputRoot.MatterGUID"
}
```

However, doing that will pass only the MatterId through to the endpoint, not all the other properties - I can understand why that happens but would like to know what i'm missing in order to include the entire object but with the changed MatterGUID value.

Almost like if I could run a replaceAll on the model and for it to affect only the property I'd like:
`$inputRoot.Replace("MatterGUID", "MatterId")`

Answer (score 0):

The model is not the source of truth on **what** the payload should contain, the mapping template is. It is currently not possible to include properties within the payload that are defined in the model and not present in the mapping template.

Comment: Does that then mean that I would need to include the entire model for each mapping template that i would like customized? i.e. use the `Generate Template` within the body mapping, and adjust the property as i wish?